# Using a PivotTable to get the count of a maximum value

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot-table

I'm using Excel 2007 (which, sadly, lacks many of the cool pivot table features included with 2010 and beyond) and have some data for which I'm attempting to get a count of the number of times each maximum value occurs for a given `SiteID`.

Each site has the same patients that come in, and I need to know how many patients have been in for `visit 1`, `visit 2`, etc. This information is used to determine how much material to send to a give site for a clinical trial. I have something like:

```
SiteID  |PatientID  |VisitNumber  
1001    |101        |1  
1001    |101        |2  
1001    |102        |1  
1001    |102        |2  
1001    |102        |3  
3004    |110        |1  
3004    |110        |2  
3004    |110        |3  
3004    |123        |1  
3004    |123        |2  
3004    |123        |3
```

The result for this sample data would be:

site 1001, 1 patient at `visit 2` and 1 at `visit 3`
site 3004, 2 patients at `visit 3`

I can do this fairly easily with a formula and some other tools, but my coworker wants it to be in the form of a PivotTable. If I were doing this myself, I'd use this array formula:

```
{=MAX(IF(IF($A$2:$A$2267=A2,$D$2:$D$2267,FALSE)=D2,$F$2:$F$2267,FALSE))}
```

on each line, and then I'd use remove duplicates and a COUNTIFS() formula to get the result.

Surely a PivotTable has an easier solution?

Comment: Well, I am not sure how much it saves you from the solution you offered.
You will need to make 2 pivots.
The first will show for each site and patient what is his max visit. 
and 2nd will summaries the data. In any case you will need to extract the values out of it which is a lot of work.

Comment: Hi Balinti. Thanks for your response. I'm getting the impression that this might not be a pivot-table-friendly task. Maybe I'll stick with the formulaic approach.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect I either don't understand the question or have forgotten some of Excel 2007 limitations. In Excel 2013 I *think* you want the heading for the last value on the right that is not `0`:

[image: SO32213594 example]

Comment: Hi pnuts, thanks for the answer and cleaning up the question. (And apologies for the delayed response - I had some personal issues). Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for Excel-2007, or at least I can't get it to. In my research before asking the question, I noted that there were some improvements made after Excel-2007 that would make this pretty easy to do, but sadly don't. I'll keep trying and update my comment if I can get it to work.

Comment: I'm sorry, for some reason I thought you were suggesting connecting the two pivot tables, which is actually what I need to do. Unfortunately Excel 2007 doesn't seem to have an easy way to do this without VBA. I've got the VBA solution mostly worked out. I'll post it here when done. I was trying to avoid VBA so I don't have to deal with user discomfort. 

(Unrelated aside, thank you for what you do here. Anytime I go to answer or ask a question, there's usually some valuable input from you. You really are a pillar of the community here.)